Gyroscope sensor drift problem at speed
I have an iPhone mounted on a bike to measure the slope of the road in real-time. This works pretty well at first but as soon as I speed up, the reported pitch starts to drift. I'm using CoreMotion which uses sensor fusion from the gyro, magnetometer and pitch. I'm applying Kalman Filter to remove the noise and get rid of any noise from vibrations and road bumps.
I tried pairing the data with the GPS Altitude data but the altitude change data is pretty inaccurate, making it difficult to measure the slope. I then tried using the altimeter to measure the difference in elevation but the GPS locations are inaccurate, making the altimeter data useless if I want to calculate the slope.
Is there a possible direct correlation between the gyroscope drift and the speed that I can use in theory to adjust the drift in real-time? Is there any other approach you would suggest to address this problem? Perhaps, would it make more sense to rely exclusively on a specific sensor rather than the sensor fusion algorithm that Apple implemented?

There is no correlation, gyroscope drift is similar (if not precisely) a random walk process. Your approach of using a Kalman to optimize the inputs from multiple sensors sounds like the best approach. You may have great difficulty in getting something close to an instantaneous slope but I would expect your results to improve on the avg (the average slope between two points with greater accuracy but less resolution the further the points are apart).  Just grasping at straws; perhaps another input like barometric P_b can give you the finer resolution you desire (together w/ the other sensors)

Thanks @DanBoschen (as discuss on the phone - thank you for your generous time), the altimeter is a good strategy but still relies on inaccurate readings from the GPS. Upon further inspection, I found the altimeter itself is not very predictable.

@DanBoschen: there is a vibration-related gyroscope drift -- so in the presence of vibration in rotation you can't count on gyro offset (or, for that matter, accelerometer offset) to be steady.  It's called "coning" (for gyros) and "sculling" (for accelerometers).  It has to do with the fact that rotation is a nonlinear phenomenon.  I'm not sure if that's what's happening here, but if the phone's underlying sampling process is slow, or if the phone or Elie's code is subsampling naively, then it could be the problem.

@TimWescott I'm sampling at 100hz. Though, I'm not handling the rotationRate. I'm relying on Apple's SensorFusion algorithm (closed source) which generates the pitch measurement. I'm guessing that when accelerating on descents, Apple's algorithm is sensing some free fall, affecting their gravity estimation. What's surprising though is that it's taking a while to recalibrate itself.

@TimWescott I ran more tests today. I tested on a smooth road and offroad. You're correct. The repeated bumps are what's causing the offset. Do you have any suggestions on how to address this?

Your problem should be quite easily avoidable, which makes me think something has been overlooked. Either that, or our definitions of "drift" differ. As commented by others, a constant velocity will not have any effect on any readings, regardless of the speed, as physics tells us there is no way to fundamentally say whether something is moving or not.
You want to estimate the road slope from the inclination of your iPhone. The iPhone's 3 axis accelerometer reading of the gravitational acceleration vector directly provides this. There will be other components to its reading, but they should average out to zero (unless you are continuously going round in a circle, etc). Therefore, you could just low pass filter the accelerometer readings and use that alone (which is how inclinometers work), particularly as the road slope probably doesn't vary rapidly.
To obtain a higher frequency response, a Kalman filter or complementary filter to combine accelerometer data with other sensors is possible, but the implementation should still use the accelerometer to prevent drift.
Are you sure the iPhone mount isn't slipping and rotating about your handlebars or similar, thereby causing a gradual drift in its inclination?
Update on data fusion:
If acceleration disturbances don't average to insignificant levels within a time scale less than your accelerometer's low pass filter time constant, then it will noticeably affect the inclination estimation. You then have no choice but to increase the low pass filter time constant. If doing so means that you no longer obtain an adequately fast response to road inclination changes, then you will need to combine data from different sensors using a sensor fusion algorithm.
You ask about combining accelerators with gyroscopes. Gyroscopes have time-varying bias that cause drift. As such, your fusion algorithm must have online gyroscope bias correction, as simply zeroing the gyroscope readings when not rotating will probably be inadequate.
Since you want real-time estimates, your only option for a data fusion algorithm is filtering, which can either be complementary or stochastic, both of which can achieve similar performance and can be considered equally effective according to a literature review I conducted five years ago, with the most common complementary filters being the Mahony complementary filter and Madgwick complementary filter, and the most accurate stochastic filter being the error state extended Kalman filter with a global orientation error parameterisation. I'd suggest starting with the Mahony complementary filter as he did work with cheap IMUs characterised by low-resolution signals subject to high noise levels as well as general time-varying bias terms, which is about as bad as it can get.
At the URL below, you will find a link to source code for the Mahony complementary filter and the Madgwick complementary filter (that is, the C code download link towards the bottom of the page), but note that only the Mahony implementation has online gyroscope bias correction, yet if you open the original internal report link also found there, that document has source code for the Madgwick complementary filter with online gyroscope bias correction at the end: https://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/
Update on noise:
The sensitivity of low-cost gyroscope output to vibration can be significant (https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/gyro-mechanical-performance.html), which is quantified on datasheets, but I'm not sure what model the iPhone uses to look it up. When we worked on developing an orientation estimation solution, we developed a vibration isolator for acceleration reasons, which would have also reduced noise due to sensor vibration sensitivity. It's too long ago to recall why, but coning and sculling doesn't appear explicitly in my literature review, other than perhaps through a general statement that vibration should be compensated for, but I can see it was a consideration and all the sensors we were looking at had coning and sculling compensation built in.
In general, the sensitivity of the data fusion filter output to noise is dependent on how you tune it, and again, Mahony did his work with IMUs characterised by high noise in an environment that has vibration. In contrast, Madgwick's gyroscope was so good that to demonstrate his complementary filter worked with respect to gyroscope bias, he had to artificially introduce it, but he only did so for a constant amount, and he manipulated his setup by hand, which won't produce any significant vibration, and whilst that's not evidence Mahony inherently will outperform Madgwick, it's just that Mahony's has been demonstrated in applications that I think more closely approximate what you are doing, which is why I suggest starting with Mahony's.
Update on testing
I fully developed a strategy for using only an accelerometer and ran some tests it to prove its operation. It is based on the inclination being defined by the angle between the bicycle's roll (longitudinal) axis and gravity.
Firstly, I mounted an Xsens MTi-3 on my bicycle's frame in the hope that its orientation relative to my bicycle's roll axis would remain fixed, rather than, say, if it was mounted on the handlebars.
Secondly, to identify the bicycle roll axis in the sensor's reference frame I leant the bicycle to both sides as far as I could before the pedals touched the ground before starting my ride and at the end of my ride, which rotated the bicycle about its roll axis, then fit a normal to the plane of accelerometer data points by computing the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of:
$$(\bf{A}^T\bf{A})\bf{v}=\lambda\bf{v}$$
Where I take the eigenvector, $\bf{v}$, corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue, $\lambda$, which is parallel to the bicycle's roll axis, and then I reverse it if necessary so that it is pointing forward. The matrix $\bf{A}$ is:
$$\bf{A}=[\bf{a_x},\bf{a_y},\bf{a_z}]$$
Where $\bf{a_x}$, $\bf{a_y}$, and $\bf{a_z}$ are column vectors of the accelerometer's x, y, and z axis readings with their means subtracted, respectively. Here, on the left, is a 3D graphical representation of the accelerometer data (blue) and the computed roll axis vector (red), and on the right it shows how much the inclination estimate varies when using this roll axis during the roll axis identification (less than 1 degree variation for almost 135 degree roll):

Thirdly, I filtered my accelerometer data with a 0.1 hz first order low pass filter, which seemed adequate as it kept the inclination estimation variation within +/- 0.5 degrees when riding, albeit the frequency of oscillation was approximately 2.5 hz, so possibly that was a disturbance associated with my cadence that was perhaps exacerbated by my front suspension compressing at that frequency (I used a 100 hz sample rate). I could have used filtered data in the bicycle roll axis identification but didn't simply as there was very little noise due to doing it in such a controlled way.
Finally, I computed the inclination, $\theta$, over the course of the ride using:
$$\theta={\rm asin}\left[\frac{\bf{a}}{|\bf{a}|}\cdot\bf{v}\right]$$
Where $\bf{a}$ is the filtered accelerometer reading vector.
Here is the output over the course of my 38 minute ride:

The most significant problem was variation in the orientation of my sensor relative to my bicycle, as evidenced by a 2.9 degree change in the bicycle roll axis in the sensor reference frame between the start and end of the ride, which was significant compared to the variation in the inclination. If I was to take this further, that would be the most important problem to solve first as I simply mounted the sensor with rubberbands and blutack, which resisted, but did not prevent, changes in relative orientation. The other problems appear may be due to my bicycle having suspension, which were (1) noticeable jumps in the inclination estimation when stopping and starting, which may be due to me unloading and loading my bicycle's suspension due to putting a foot down to rest; and (2) oscillation in the inclination estimate at twice the cadence frequency, which may be due to compressing my suspension at that frequency, however this can trivially be eliminated using a notch filter at twice the cadence frequency.
Here is Matlab code for the above:
 % output columns 3, 4, and 5 correspond to accelerometer x, y, and z
 time = output(:,2);     % s
 a_xyz = output(:,3:5);  % m/s^2

 % filter accelerometer data with initialisation to remove initial dc offset
 w0 = 2*pi*0.1;
 T = 1/100;
 b = w0*T*[1,1];
 a = [w0*T+2, w0*T-2];
 z_rev = cumsum(b(end:-1:2)-a(end:-1:2))/a(1); z = z_rev(end:-1:1)*a_xyz(1,:);
 a_xyz_filt = filter(b, a, a_xyz, z);

 % compute the bicycle roll axis (two datasets are available, one at the
 % start and the other at the end of the ride, which I average to determine
 % the average roll axis in the sensor reference frame)
 roll_axis = zeros(3,1);
 for k = 1:2
     subplot(1,1,1); plot(output(:,3:5))
     title(sprintf('zoom in on dataset %d region of interest',k));
     zoom on
     pause
     ind = round(xlim);

     a_xyz_seg = a_xyz(ind(1):ind(2),:);
     A = a_xyz_seg - repmat(mean(a_xyz_seg),ind(2)-ind(1)+1,1);
     [v,d] = eig(A'*A,'vector');
     [~,idx] = min(abs(d));

     % the eigenvector happens to be pointing anti-parallel (that is, in my
     % particular case, I have to reverse it for it to point forward on my
     % bicycle)
     v = -v(:,idx);

     % visualise results
     subplot(1,2,1); plot3(a_xyz_seg(:,1), a_xyz_seg(:,2), a_xyz_seg(:,3),'.'); grid on
     line([0, v(1)]*10+mean(a_xyz_seg(:,1)),[0,v(2)]*10+mean(a_xyz_seg(:,2)),[0,v(3)]*10+mean(a_xyz_seg(:,3)))
     xlabel('x (m/s^2)')
     ylabel('y (m/s^2)')
     zlabel('z (m/s^2)')
     axis equal
     rotate3d on
     title('identifying bicycle roll axis')

     a = a_xyz_filt./repmat(sqrt(sum(a_xyz_filt.^2,2)),1,3);
     inclination = asind(a(ind(1):ind(2),:)*v);
     subplot(1,2,2); plot(inclination); title('estimated inclination during roll axis identification');
     ylabel('inclination (degrees)')

     pause   % to allow user to see visual results

     roll_axis = v + roll_axis;
 end
 roll_axis = roll_axis/norm(roll_axis);

 % estimate inclination
 a = a_xyz_filt./repmat(sqrt(sum(a_xyz_filt.^2,2)),1,3);
 inclination = asind(a*roll_axis);

 % display results
 clf
 clear ah
 ah(1) = subplot(3,1,1); plot(time/60, a_xyz); grid on; title('accelerometer unfiltered (m/s^2)'); xlabel('time (min)'); legend({'a_x','a_y','a_z'})
 ah(2) = subplot(3,1,2); plot(time/60, a_xyz_filt); grid on; title('accelerometer filtered (m/s^2)'); xlabel('time (min)')
 ah(3) = subplot(3,1,3); plot(time/60, inclination); grid on; title('inclination estimate (degrees)'); xlabel('time (min)')
 zoom on
 linkaxes(ah,'x');
 axis tight


Hi Stephen, what you're suggesting is reasonable. I actually just ran some tests. I applied a low pass filter with a dynamic alpha value (calculated based on how close the magnitude is to G) which helped me eliminate the noise. While the shape looks good, it seems that the numbers are offset by roughly -12 degrees.
Note that I have to account for the mount angle. I'm updating the question with the code following your suggestion.

I may have figured it out. I'll follow up tomorrow after I run some tests.

I ran some tests and it appears that in many cases, particularly when the cyclist is freewheeling, the user acceleration is having an impact on the low pass filtered data (unlike the jerky movements from pedaling for example). Would leveraging the gyroscope in this situation help address this issue?

I'll add some notes to my answer on how a gyroscope might be used to not be constrained by the character limit in these comments.

Thanks Stephen. I'm working on implementing both filters (might take a few days) and I'll report back.

I also left a comment regarding the cause of the offset. It turns out it's not necessarily the speed or constant acceleration. It's more correlated with the vibrations (bad roads) that are more frequent when speeding. Do you think the Mahony or the Madgwick filters could take care of this?

I have added a section on comments on noise. Note that these data fusion algorithms are for combining different sensors, rather than filtering and using a single sensor. For the latter, just low pass filter, as you are doing already. Do you know whether the vibrations are causing the accelerometer to exceed its range? If so, then you'll need to build some kind of vibration isolator, and since you are limited to 100hz, it might be worth it either way to minimise aliasing.

My apologies, I should have picked my words more carefully. Small vibrations are not impacting the data, it's the bumps that I'm referring to. For example, I was riding on a 1% descent on a concrete bridge that has 1 inch expansion joint (unfilled) every 2 feet for about 30 feet. My grade pitch went from -1% to -100%. This is the worst I've seen my pitch data drift. I'll continue to experiment with Mahoney to see what happens.

That's odd. If I've got the units right, I guess you're riding at least 12 mph, so those two feet separated expansion joints would produce a pulse at a rate of at least 10 hz, which I would think is well above your accelerometer low pass filter bandwidth. Perhaps share the raw sensor data and the code you are processing it with, and I'll take a look to see if there is anything obvious. I've found I've still got an Xsens MTi-3, which I'll use and develop the same thing you're doing so both of us can be trying to solve this one.

Awesome. I uploaded the dataset into this gist on github: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eliekhoury/4774a32416030c3faa9c83e04b601d40/raw/14d44ffef8c73c7de6b069e9fef14eefaa606410/gistfile1.txt.
You'll find 3 sections in this ride session where the iPhone sensor data were recorded. This dataset doesn't have the bumpy road that I mentioned since I observed it but the pitch is drifting in all 3 sections. If you prefer a cleaner dataset, I can record some tomorrow.
For the Mahoney implementation, here's the class I have: https://gist.github.com/eliekhoury/80dafeebeb671e1cf26396d178aae2b5

In your data, what corresponds to the raw accelerometer data (you have "acceleration", which isn't it, and "gravity" whose magnitude is always equal to 1, so isn't it either)? Also, I noticed that "timestamp" is quite irregular, in contrast to "interval", and that "interval" suggests a sample interval slightly less than 50hz whereas I thought you sampled at 100hz?

It’s acceleration + gravity, that would give us the raw accelerometer data.

My apologies, you’re right, this was collected at 50hz. I’ll upload in an hour a 100hz shorter sample.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So you want to estimate the instantaneous angle of the terrain (presumably mainly in the direction of travel of the bike)?
Can you not read that directly from magnetometer and/or gravity field sensors, if the phone is mounted flat (or at a known angle) relative to the bike?
